# What files should I add to a VCS?

Tags: cordova, version-control

I'm in a Cordova/Phonegap project. There's a `platforms/` directory holding platform settings and deployments. Other directories such as `merges/` are part of the project, but I have my doubts with the `platforms/` directory.

What files, if any, inside `platforms/` should I add to, say, Git? (I assume the rest of the files should be ignored).